# segmentation fault in C comparing integer members from structure to array in main

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, structure

I get segmentation fault in the line below.

```
if((rel[i].node1 == SI && rel[i].node2 == gates[j]) || (rel[i].node2 == SI && rel[i].node1 == gates[j])
```

Now, all the variables/members are integers and they are initialized.
I don't really know what to do.
I tryied to change indexes as well.

I hope to get some help, thank you in advance.

Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/**
 * Auto-generated code below aims at helping you parse
 * the standard input according to the problem statement.
 **/
struct relationship {
   int node1;
   int node2;
};

int main()
{

    int N; // the total number of nodes in the level, including the gateways
    int L; // the number of links
    int E; // the number of exit gateways
    scanf("%d%d%d", &N, &L, &E);

    int gates[E];
    struct relationship rel[L];

    for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        int N1; // N1 and N2 defines a link between these nodes
        int N2;
        scanf("%d%d", &N1, &N2);
        rel[i].node1 = N1;
        rel[i].node2 = N2;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < E; i++) {
        int EI; // the index of a gateway node
        scanf("%d", &EI);
        gates[i] = EI;
    }

    while (1) {
        int SI; // The index of the node on which the Skynet agent is positioned this turn
        scanf("%d", &SI);

        int i, j;
        for(i=0; i < L; i++){

            //for(j=0; j <E; j++){

                if((rel[i].node1 == SI && rel[i].node2 == gates[j]) || (rel[i].node2 == SI && rel[i].node1 == gates[j])) {
                    printf("%d %d ood\n", rel[i].node1, rel[i].node2);
                    rel[i].node1 = -1;
                    rel[i].node2 = -1;

                }
           // }
            /*if(SI == rel[i].node1 || SI ==rel[i].node2){
                printf("%d %d %d \n", rel[i].node1, rel[i].node2, SI);
               //printf("%d %d\n", rel[i].node1, rel[i].node2);
               rel[i].node1 = -1;
               rel[i].node2 = -1;
               break;
            }*/
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can find the whole program here http://collabedit.com/g4p4d

Comment: you're obviously accessing an index that is out of bounds. Make sure all memory is properly allocated for each array.

Comment: Thanks for the link!  Would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40263522/edit) to include the relevant pieces of the program?  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.

Comment: What is the input ?

Comment: It's an online game for programmer, the input is given by the website. Do rules allow me to say the name of the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not initialise j, thus `gates[j]` ends up with a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thank you!!!! I didn't notice i've put the for with j=0 in the comments. Stupid error, you probably saved me an afternoon.

Comment: @Emanuele learn how to use a debugger, that will save you lots of afternoons in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You commented out this line:

```
//for(j=0; j <E; j++){
```

and therefore `j` is not initialized, and therefore `gates[j]` yields in undefined behaviour, in your case a segfault.